# Using pointer as a template parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

In C++ I can do something like this:

```
template <typename T, T* Ptr>
class MyClass {};
```

I have two questions:

1. Where can I get a pointer other than nullptr in compile time?
2. How can I use this language feature? Of course, it would be interesting for practical cases, but it seems that this is a rather specific possibility, so an artificial example will also be suitable.

Comment: You can get a pointer to anything with static storage duration and linkage at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a pointer to anything with static storage duration and linkage at compile time:

```
static const int values[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
MyClass <const int, values> myClass;

static char magic = '*';
MyClass <char, &magic> myClass2;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/adEe5n)

Comment: When it can be useful?

Comment: Whereas you need constexpr pointer in template, might be useful to add name to template class. I already used it to serialize classes into Json.

Comment: on option where it can be useful it in the embedded system where you have static memory maps for a different section - and it const.

Comment: @Jarod42, what means "to add name to template class"? You can also use empty struct for that. Or maybe this is one from all solutions?

Comment: It is one available tool. It (might) have alternative. Runtime pointer might also be enough. Can also be there in generic programming, so no special cases for  pointers.